# Question about notation in Wolfram's "Composition of series with power and logarithm"

Tags: notation, power-series

In this [Wolfram](http://functions.wolfram.com/GeneralIdentities/4//) webpage, under the section "For compositions with elementary functions" they give the following identities:

Power functions:

[image]

Log+power functions:

[image]

However, in those equations, the variables $m$ and $c$ in the right hand side seem to be undefined.  Are they standard variables?  What do they represent?

Comment: $m$ is the index of the first nonzero coefficient in the Taylor expansion of $f$ with centre $0$, and $c$ is that coefficient. So the Taylor expansion of $f$ starts $c\cdot (z-z_0)^m + \dotsc$.

Comment: @DavidFischer This is helpful to me.  Can you write it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f$ is an elementary function there, so analytic. Although it is not stated explicitly (unless I overlooked it), it is assumed that $f$ doesn't vanish identically. Thus $f$ has a power series expansion

$$f(z) = \sum_{n = 0} a_n \cdot (z-z_0)^n$$

valid in a neighbourhood of $z_0$, where not all coefficients $a_n$ vanish.

Possibly, they allow for $f$ to have a pole at $z_0$, then $f$ has a Laurent series expansion

$$f(z) = \sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}} a_n\cdot (z-z_0)^n$$

about $z_0$ with finite principal part - that is, only finitely many $a_n$ with a negative index $n$ may be nonzero.

$m$ is the smallest index for which the coefficient is nonzero, and $c$ is the corresponding coefficient,

$$m = \min \{ n : a_n \neq 0\},\quad\text{and}\quad c = a_m.$$

Thus we can write

$$f(z) = c(z-z_0)^m\cdot g(z)\tag{1}$$

with an analytic function

$$g(z) = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{a_{n+m}}{a_m}(z - z_0)^n$$

satisfying $g(z_0) = 1$. The principal branches of powers and logarithms have simple expansions in neighbourhoods of $1$, and so the decomposition $(1)$ together with the known behaviour of powers and logarithms for products yields the given series expansions, where the last series is the expansion of the principal branch of the $b$-th power resp. logarithm of

$$c^{-r}\biggl(\frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^m}\biggr)^r = g(z)^r = 1 + \bigl( g(z)^r-1\bigr).$$

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that
$m$ is an integer
(perhaps positive)
and $c$ is the limit
towards the end.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: The author asked what they represented. I made a guess.